# Debug AWS SAM in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to debug my `\event` endpoint using AWS SAM in VSCode and I'm having issues with two of the configurations I've tried. The Direct Invoke Configuration I've used successfully in a different project, but in my current project it returns this error even though template.yaml and package.json are both in the EventsApi project directory.

```
{
      "type": "aws-sam",
      "request": "direct-invoke",
      "name": "Direct Invoke Config",
      "invokeTarget": {
          "target": "api",
          "templatePath": "template.yaml",
          "logicalId": "AddEventFunction"            
      },
      "api": {
          "path": "/event",
          "httpMethod": "post",
          "payload": {
          }
      }
  }
```

which produces this error

```
[ERROR]: SamLaunchRequestError: Failed to run launch configuration
     -> Error: Cannot find package.json for: C:/aws/EventsApi/template.yaml
```

And the second configuration, which I attach in the SAM CLI to my AddEventFunction lambda in debug mode, then the debugger catches exceptions but won't hit any endpoints with this configuration. Please note that `stopOnEntry` is unable to be added to the attach configuration for some reason.

```
    {
      "name": "Attach to SAM CLI Config",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 5858,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/handlers",
      "remoteRoot": "",
      "sourceMaps": true,
    },
```

I expect the first configuration to find package.json just fine, and the second configuration to hit a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. It turns out to start debugging only when invokeTarget.target is "code".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure for your template.yaml have the *CodeUri: path/here* param, so it can find the package.json in your folder, i was having the same problem, and have addind this solved it, hope this helps!

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: A simple project using SAM
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  OrchestratorSqs:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
       CodeUri: ./ # Same level as the package.json file
       Handler: app.runner
       ...
```